# How to tell if an estimator is good by reading results of Monte Carlo simulations?

Tags: estimation, model, monte-carlo

I'm new to parameter estimation world and I'm studying a model with two parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$:
$$
  dX_t = \mu X_t dt + \sigma X_t dB_t^H
$$
where $B_t^H$ is a fractional Brownian motion (fBm) with Hurst parameter $H\in(0,1)$ (FYI I had asked another question about estimation of $H$ [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/451282/how-does-monte-carlo-method-for-parameter-estimation-work-in-practice)).

After getting the formulas for the estimators of the parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$, I tried to test their goodness in the following way (which I think is called Monte Carlo experiment, isn't it?):

1. Choose stepsize $dt=10^{-1}$ and discretize the time interval $[0,1]$ in $11$ equidistant points (in matlab this is obtained with `0:dt:1`);
2. Fix the values of the parameters, for example $\mu = 2$, $\sigma = 0.5$ and $H=0.8$, and fix an initial value, for example $x_1=1$, then generate $N=10$ sample paths of synthetic data of size $11$: so $10$ vectors of size $11$ are generated, each vector is of the form ($x_1, x_2, ..., x_{11}$);
3. Plug each sample in the formulas of the estimators, hence we obtain $10$ estimates of $\mu$ and $10$ estimates of $\sigma$;
4. Denote with $\hat\mu = (\hat\mu_1,...,\hat\mu_{10})$ and with $\hat\sigma = (\hat\sigma_1,...,\hat\sigma_{10})$ the vectors containing the estimates computed in step 3. Then compute $\text{mean}(\hat\mu)$, $\text{std}(\hat\mu)$, $\text{BIAS}(\hat\mu)$, $\text{MSE}(\hat\mu)$, and $\text{mean}(\hat\sigma)$, $\text{std}(\hat\sigma)$, $\text{BIAS}(\hat\sigma)$, $\text{MSE}(\hat\sigma)$.

About the last step, recall that given a parameter $\theta$ and a collection $\hat\theta$ of $n$ estimates

- $\text{mean}(\hat\theta) = E[\hat\theta] = \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\hat\theta_i$
- $\text{std}(\hat\theta) = \sqrt{\text{var}(\hat\theta)}$, where $\text{var}(\hat\theta) = E[(\hat\theta-E[\hat\theta])^2]$
- $\text{BIAS}(\hat\theta) = E[\hat\theta]-\theta$
- $\text{MSE}(\hat\theta) = E[(\hat\theta-\theta)^2] \equiv \text{var}(\hat\theta)+\text{BIAS}(\hat\theta)^2$

I then repeated the 4 steps using $dt=10^{-2}$, $dt=10^{-3}$ and $dt=10^{-4}$. Then I repeated all again, generating $N=100$ and $N=1000$ samples. Result are listed in the following tables

$\begin{array}{c|c|rcc}
    N & dt & \text{BIAS}(\hat\mu) & \text{MSE}(\hat\mu) & \text{mean}(\hat\mu)\pm\text{std}(\hat\mu) \\
    \hline
     10 & 10^{-1} & 0.0791 & 0.1703 & 2.0791\pm0.4051 \\
     10 & 10^{-2} & 0.1548 & 0.2126 & 2.1548\pm0.4343 \\
     10 & 10^{-3} & -0.0233 & 0.1211 & 1.9767\pm0.3472 \\
     10 & 10^{-4} & 0.0148 & 0.0767 & 2.0148\pm0.2766 \\
     \hline
     100 & 10^{-1} & -0.0605 & 0.1275 & 1.9395\pm0.3518 \\
     100 & 10^{-2} & 0.0131 & 0.1818 & 2.0131\pm0.4262 \\
     100 & 10^{-3} & 0.0205 & 0.2185 & 2.0205\pm0.4670 \\
     100 & 10^{-4} & -0.0081 & 0.0890 & 1.9919\pm0.2983 \\
     \hline
     1000 & 10^{-1} & -0.0018 & 0.1166 & 1.9982\pm0.3415 \\
     1000 & 10^{-2} & -0.0156 & 0.1622 & 1.9844\pm0.4024 \\
     1000 & 10^{-3} & -0.0252 & 0.2311 & 1.9748\pm0.4800 \\
     1000 & 10^{-4} & 0.0266 & 0.1157 & 2.0266\pm0.3391
\end{array}$

$\begin{array}{c|c|ccc}
    N & dt & \text{BIAS}(\hat\sigma) & \text{MSE}(\hat\sigma) & \text{mean}(\hat\sigma)\pm\text{std}(\hat\sigma) \\
    \hline
     10 & 10^{-1} & -0.2257 & 0.0544 & 0.2743\pm0.0594 \\
     10 & 10^{-2} & -0.1152 & 0.0139 & 0.3848\pm0.0238 \\
     10 & 10^{-3} & -0.0314 & 0.0013 & 0.4686\pm0.0182 \\
     10 & 10^{-4} & -0.1673 & 0.0280 & 0.3327\pm0.0043 \\
     \hline
     100 & 10^{-1} & -0.2444 & 0.0639 & 0.2556\pm0.0646 \\
     100 & 10^{-2} & -0.1216 & 0.0164 & 0.3784\pm0.0400 \\
     100 & 10^{-3} & -0.0267 & 0.0011 & 0.4733\pm0.0202 \\
     100 & 10^{-4} & -0.1674 & 0.0281 & 0.3326\pm0.0053 \\
     \hline
     1000 & 10^{-1} & -0.2416 & 0.0631 & 0.2584\pm0.0688 \\
     1000 & 10^{-2} & -0.1265 & 0.0172 & 0.3735\pm0.0347 \\
     1000 & 10^{-3} & -0.0251 & 0.0010 & 0.4749\pm0.0185 \\
     1000 & 10^{-4} & -0.1674 & 0.0281 & 0.3326\pm0.0053 
\end{array}$

- Since the BIAS is never 0, then the estimators of the paramaters $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are not unbiased.
- $\text{BIAS}(\hat\mu)$, $\text{MSE}(\hat\mu)$ and $\text{std}(\hat\mu)$ don't decrease neither by increasing $N$ nor by decreasing $dt$.
- $\text{BIAS}(\hat\sigma)$ are all negative, is this called "left bias"?
- $\text{BIAS}(\hat\sigma)$ and $\text{MSE}(\hat\sigma)$ decrease from $dt=10^{-1}$ to $dt=10^{-3}$, but increase with $dt=10^{-4}$.
- $\text{std}(\hat\sigma)$ decreases as $dt$ decreases.

What else can be noticed? What can be said about the goodness of the estimators?

Comment: I don't have time to read this now but I suggest that  write the original expression somewhere so that people that are new to this thread and didn't read the other one, can understand better what it is that you're estimating.